# MariaDB schema creation

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to define a set of objects in MariaDB, namely

```
use SocialCartography;

drop table if exists Relationship;
drop table if exists Person;

create table if not exists Person (
    Id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    Name varchar(255) null, 
    DoB date null,
    DoD date null,
    PictureURL varchar(8192) null
);

create table if not exists Relationship (
    Id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    Since date null,
    Until date null,
    Type varchar(255),
    First int unsigned not null,
    Second int unsigned not null,
    PictureURL varchar(8192) null,

    constraint `fk_first_friend` 
    foreign key (first) references Person (Id)
        on delete cascade
        on update restrict,

    constraint `fk_second_friend` 
    foreign key (second) references Person (Id)
        on delete cascade
        on update restrict
);
go

delimiter //
create or replace procedure upsert_person (
    in pId int unsigned,
    in pName varchar(255),
    in pDoB date,
    in pDoD date,
    in pPictureURL varchar(8192)
)
as
begin
    if exists(select Id from Person where Id = pId) 
    then
        update Person
        set
            Name = pName,
            DoB = pDoB, 
            DoD = pDoD,
            PictureURL = pPictureURL
        where
            Id = pId;

        select pId as Id;
    else
        insert into Person
        (
            Name,
            DoB,
            DoD,
            PictureURL
        )
        values
        (p
            pName,
            pDoB,
            pDoD,
            pPictureURL
        );

        select last_insert_id() as Id;
    end if;
end //
delimiter ;

delimiter //
create or replace procedure delete_person (
    in pId int unsigned
)
begin
    delete Person
    where Id = pId;
end //
delimiter ;

delimiter //
create or replace procedure upsert_relationship ( 
    in pId int unsigned,
    in pSince date,
    in pUntil date,
    in pType nvarchar(255),
    in pFirst int unsigned,
    in pSecond int unsigned,
    in pPictureURL nvarchar(8192)
)
begin
    if exists(select Id from Relationship where Id = pId) 
    then
        update Relationship 
        set
           Since = pSince,
           Until = pUntil,
           Type = pType,
           First = pFirst,
           Second = pSecond,
           PictureURL = pPictureURL
        where
            Id = pId;

        select pId as Id;
    else
        insert into Relationship
        (
           Since,
           Until,
           Type,
           First,
           Second,
           PictureURL
        )
        values
        (
           pSince,
           pUntil,
           pType,
           pFirst,
           pSecond,
           pPictureURL
        );

        select last_insert_id() as Id;
    end if;
end //
delimiter ;

delimiter //
create or replace procedure delete_relationship (
    in pId int unsigned
)
begin
    delete Relationship
    where Id = pId;
end //
delimiter ;
```

But the error I keep getting is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 36: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'procedure upsert_person (
in pId int unsigned,
in pName varchar(255),
' at line 1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I already tried nvarchar, but reverted back to varchar because I could find scant documentation on how to use nvarchar.

The error message doesn't seem overly helpful as I've tried to find an error near the syntax indicated, but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `go`; that belongs in other products.

`OR REPLACE` is not available until 10.1.3; what version are you running?

[*Reference*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-procedure/#or-replace)